# Replace one part text element in a for loop Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, replace, formatting

My goal is to change a word in a sentence and write into a text file.

I created a text file:

```
filename = "/Users/Adam/Desktop/data.txt"
text = open(filename, 'r')
lines = text.readlines()
```

I have got this example sentence : "I have got a RED cat"

I want to change the "RED", the colour name, and write (append) every sentence to my data.txt.

```
colours={red, blue, yellow, green, etc..}
```

How can I take it into a loop, replace only this part and write every senctence to my txt file?

EDITED - Sanket request:

> For example i start my text here, what is a paragraph so i want this tabulator or space before it in the .txt file too.......
>   asfgas
>   sagsaasgsagasgsagsaaggaggggg

And i continue my senctence when i arrive at "I have got a RED cat"

And after that my text is continuing.

EDIT2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/bin/sh
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib2
import subprocess
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io

array = ["https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/gdn/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ktw/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/krk/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/wmi/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/poz/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/waw/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/wro/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/otp/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/clj/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tsr/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bts/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lju/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/alc/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bcn/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bio/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/fue/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/gro/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/grx/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ibz/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/xry/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ace/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mad/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/agp/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/pmi/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mah/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mjv/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/reu/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/sdr/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/scq/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/svq/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tfs/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tfn/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/vlc/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/zaz/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/abz/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bfs/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bhd/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bhx/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/brs/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/cwl/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ema/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/edi/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/gla/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/pik/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/huy/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/jer/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lba/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lpl/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ltn/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lhr/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lcy/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bqh/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/stn/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lgw/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/man/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/sou/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ncl/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/vie/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/brq/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/prg/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bud/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/deb/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/boj/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/sof/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/var/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ork/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/dub/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/noc/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/kir/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/snn/departures", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mla/departures"]

string = ("browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]
   browser.get('%s')  WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active==0"))
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Load earlier flights")]').click()
time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
 \n")

file="/Users/Adam/Desktop/data.txt"

with open(file, "w") as f:
    for i in array:
        f.write(string % i)

f.close()
```

Comment: Edit question with your code that you tried so far...   @Harley

Comment: This is a bit pedantic but that's not Python at all. Do you mean colours should be like `colours = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green']`? Or are `red`, `blue` etc defined names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we can do something like the below:

```
array = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green"]

string = ("I have got a %s cat.\n")

file="file.txt"

with open(file, "w") as f:
    for i in array:
        f.write(string % i)
```

---

To answer your above question in the comments. Yes, this will still work if you have multiple paragraphs:

```
array = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green"]

string = ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque at hendrerit enim, ut sodales arcu. Donec vel purus vel orci consequat ultrices et vitae metus. Donec auctor, elit placerat porttitor accumsan, diam massa faucibus justo, eu egestas eros leo a nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur elementum at ante quis auctor. Pellentesque egestas massa id dolor bibendum, a aliquet dui fermentum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc luctus mollis ligula, vel condimentum enim semper ac.\n\nI have got a %s cat.\n\nIn risus velit, gravida ac nisl a, rutrum pulvinar mi. In et enim vel ex vehicula ultrices. Donec facilisis pellentesque ultricies. Cras ultrices nec ipsum tincidunt cursus. Integer et libero rhoncus, malesuada orci a, pellentesque mi. Quisque vitae fringilla sapien. Proin sit amet erat erat. Vivamus id condimentum ligula. Donec lobortis tincidunt egestas. In convallis rutrum laoreet.\n\nSed ligula sem, mollis ac varius ac, laoreet et arcu. Integer id enim sollicitudin, eleifend nisi vitae, sagittis massa. Etiam eleifend rhoncus varius. Vestibulum condimentum nibh arcu, nec egestas dolor convallis eu. Sed gravida metus elit, vitae dictum augue vestibulum at. Aenean facilisis ipsum vel tincidunt facilisis. In interdum vitae mauris at malesuada.\n\n\n")

file="file.txt"

with open(file, "w") as f:
    for i in array:
        f.write(string % i)
```

---

On a side note, believe it or not we can condense the whole thing down to one line:

```
open("file.txt", "w").write("\n".join("I have got a %s cat." % i for i in ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green"])+"\n")
```

Python is wonderful sometimes.

Comment: @Harley Yes, if you use multiple paragraphs it will work

Comment: So i just have to put \n before my sentences and it is working?

Comment: @Harley `\n` is the return character, it's added to any plain text document when you press Enter. So wherever you would normally press Enter, add `\n`.

Comment: And where i just used some SPACE this format is staying too?

Comment: @Harley As in space characters? Yes they will stay. Have you actually run my snippet, it has space characters in it.

Comment: And if i used 2-3 space it is working too? Unfortunetly my computer is crashed, so i can try it only at the week-end, but i am still thinking about it

Comment: @Harley Yes, the string will be formatted however you want it to as long as you enter the character/s.

Comment: I tried, but it is not working. I have to write this text in a row and put /s and /n in everywhere where i want a space or paragraph??

Comment: For example, i tried it now with a code part (with 5 rows) and it is not working.

Comment: @Harley No, `\n` is a newline character, you use that to insert a new line. To insert a space just use the character that comes out when you press the spacebar. `\s` doesn't have any special quality.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you check my edit, why this code is not working?

Comment: I edited it, i tried to change here the link for example and write into a txt

Comment: @Harley Join me in chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155595/discussion-between-ethan-field-and-harley

Answer (score 2):

```
filename = "/data.txt"
text = open(filename, 'w')
colours=['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green']
for c in colours:
    line = "I have got a %s cat\n" % c
    text.write(line)
text.close()
```

Comment: I don't see the need for `w+` here. It would probably help if you mentioned `with` or `.close`, too.

Comment: And what about if I have got more senctence? With a paragraph and with a few lines. It is working too? So i want to say that I have got for example 2-3 paragraph before this senctence, and after this senctence there are more 2-3 paragraph. My format is staying in the correct form?

Comment: not getting you properly,  better you mention this points in your question, what exactly you want

Answer (score 2):

Append the following code to your script

```
text.close()
text = open(filename, 'a')
line = "I have got a %s cat\n"
colours= ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green']
for colour in colours:
    text.write(line %color)

text.close()
```

**P.S. Never forget to close your file handles**

Comment: There's no need to build a list here, you can just write each line as you generate it.